# geom_subplot2d: Unable to plot bar graph over map in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to plot bar graph over a map of [Germany](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ae25571c60d94ce5b7fcbf74e27c00e0) and I am doing the following:

1. Get base plot - map of Germany.(spatialpolygonfile)
2. Plot it with `geom_polygon`.
3. Load required data (below).
4. Calculate mean of position where bars should be plotted.
5. Join data.
6. Plot it using `geom_subplot2d`.

When I run the code all works fine, no error or warning. Then it just hangs at the end without showing any results. Any idea why? Your help is much appreciated.

```
options(warn=1)
library(XLConnect)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(DataCombine)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(mapproj)

###get map###
bundesl<-readOGR("data/new_shape/vg2500_bld.shp", "vg2500_bld")
bundesl$GEN<- as.character(bundesl$GEN)
###draw map- Base plot###
p <- ggplot()  + geom_polygon(data=bundesl,aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group), col = "blue4", fill = "lightgray") + theme_minimal()+ coord_map() 
p

##load data##
egg <- read.table(text="RS  Tariff
01  -5.25
02  7.16
03  6.65
04  3.10
05  3.69
06  2.49
07  1.89
08  3.93
09  -5.84
10  -2.61
11  -0.21
12  2.35
13  -5.94
14  -7.54
15  -3.27
16  -8.75", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("character", "numeric"))
colnames(eeg)<-c("RS", "Tariff")

bundesl<- fortify(bundesl)
# Calculate the mean longitude and latitude per region (places where subplots are plotted),
cntr <- ddply(bundesl,.(id),summarize,long=mean(long),lat=mean(lat))

# #### Shape Daten und EEG Daten join ####
bundesl<-merge(bundesl, eeg)

simdatmyplot  <- p+geom_subplot2d(aes(long, lat, subplot = geom_bar(aes(x = RS, y = Tariff, fill = Tariff, width=1), stat = "identity", position = "identity")), ref = NULL, data = bundesl)
simdatmyplot
```